# How to merge several valueChanges observable dynamic using RXJS operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have a dynamic form, something like this.

```
 profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    age: new FormControl(''),
    ...
  });
```

I want to do something when the value changes, so I did:

```
this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
           console.log('changed' + this.profileForm.getRawValue());
});
```

But I don't want every change from the entire form, just from some of the controls, but I can't do this approach:

> this.profileForm.controls['firstName'].valueChanges...

because my form is dynamic.
so I tried to create an array in my dynamic method, something like that will return this.

```
controlsTrigger = ['firstname', 'age'];
```

note that the last name it's should not trigger the console.log.

so I saw the merge operator from rxjs

```
merge(
    this.form.get("firstname").valueChanges,
    this.form.get("age").valueChanges,
).subscribe(() => console.log('changed'));
```

But I want to use it with dynamics controls.

Answer (score 3):

If your main problem here is, how to get `controlsTrigger` into merge, you could use `Array.map` and the spread-operator:

```
merge(
  ...controlsTrigger.map(name => this.form.get(name).valueChanges))
).subscribe(() => console.log('changed'));
```

Comment: I tried this approach but I am getting the error "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter"

Comment: @paulotarcio Which versions of TS and RxJS are you using? Works fine with TypeScript 4.6.4 and RxJS 7.5.7

Answer (score 1):

The problem with **merge operator** is that you can't tell where the emitted value is coming from so you would have to map the valueChanges and create a relation yourself. So something like this should do the trick:

```
const controls = ["lastName", "firstName"];

merge(
    ...controls.map(c =>
     this.profileForm.get(c).valueChanges.pipe(map(x => ({ control: c, value: x })))
)).subscribe(console.log);
```

If you use **combineLatest** it will emit values in the same order as the passed array of observables. BUT it emits only when each control has emitted at least once, which is not optimal if you are listening to formInputs.

Personally I would prefer subscribing to valueChanges of the whole form and execute logic when the fields you are interested in are included, but its up to you

Comment: I tried to subscribe after the whole form and execute my logic, but I couldn't do that.
How would do that?

Comment: tried this approach but I am getting the error "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter"

Comment: what's your ts and rxjs version and what compile settings you have in your tsconfig? because for me it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a pipe operator with a combination of combineLatest() and withLatestFrom() ?

```
combineLatest(this.form.get("fieldThatWillTrigger1").valueChanges, this.form.get("fieldThatWillTrigger2").valueChanges).pipe(withLatestFrom(this.form.get("fieldThatWONTTRIGGER1").valueChanges),withLatestFrom(this.form.get("fieldThatWONTTRIGGER2").valueChanges).subscribe(data => {
dosomethinghere();
});
```

THe hardpart is making it dynamic so you need to figure that one our